# placing code snippet into php

Tags: php

I need to place following code inside php code of my submission button, in order to be able to track clicks. 
    `onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'test', 'test',,, false]);"`
The code I need to put it into looks like this 
`<input id=”contact-submit” class=”button” type=”submit” value=”Submit” onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'test', 'test',,, false]);">`
The problem is the "'" marks which seem to break the code. How can I print this marks inside code? Thank you

Comment: You know that `”` is not a valid quote character, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escape them using `\` backslash

```
echo '<input id="contact-submit" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'test\', \'test\',,, false]);">';
```